# How do rapid test driven front end development

Tags: selenium, testing, tdd, web-frontend

I'm trying to rapidly develop my frontend, but every time I change my code I find myself refreshing my browser and running some macro to test whether the changes in my code solved the problem.

I tried changing the process to headless PySelenium, but it takes so long for the driver to launch every time I change my code.

I also tried Cypress.io, but after following the tutorial, the directory just didn't load.

I'm looking for a headless option that runs as fast as possible.

Comment: You can detach and attach to a running browser session https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/ though I don't know if it's actually going to be as fast as pressing a key.